# Cannot link with system32.dll using visual studio command prompt

Tags: winapi, assembly, linker, nasm, x86-64

Using link.exe with the visual studio command prompt:

```
link.exe "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\euler\asm\test" kernel32.dll
```

provides the ever helpful: `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'kernel32.dll'`
Why can't it link against a system dll?

I moved on to GoLink:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\nasm\golink.exe" /console test.obj Kernel32.dll
```

Which links just fine, but crashes as soon as I run it.
I'm using NASM `"C:\Program Files (x86)\nasm\nasm.exe" -fwin64 "test.asm"`

Here's my assembler [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/q8ucpUBu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSVC's link cannot link directly to a DLL - you'll need to use the `kernel32.lib` import library instead:

```
link.exe "C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\euler\asm\test.obj" kernel32.lib
```

You will need to make sure that the environment is set up correctly so `link.exe` can find the import library.  That's often done by the `vcvarsall.bat` (or similar) script/batch file that configures the command line window used to run the tools.  If you don't have something configuring the environment for the build tools, you'll need to pass in the location of the library, either by using the full path or by passing in a directory with the `/libpath` linker option.

I don't know what GoLink is, so I can't comment on what it's doing right or wrong...

Comment: Alrighty, it's coming together. GoLink **supposedly** imports symbols directly from the DLL and doesn't need a static library.

Comment: Sorry to comment again. So I have to use the largeaddressaware:no switch... presumably because it's x64 bit code.... My instructions arent RIP-Relative though, the code should be aware of addresses larger than 2GB... Can you shed any light on this?